# How to fix the problem that I can't match the pattern I defined in Lex?

Tags: lex

I'm writing a Lex code for scanning Verilog code, and I define a pattern that I want to match. But when I run the code, I find that the pattern I defined won't match. Where did I make a mistake?

I run the code on a Linux workstation. The flex version is 2.5.4.

```
%option c++
%option noyywrap
%{
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<string> input_vec;        /*To remember which signal is input*/

int input_num = 0;        /*To count the # of input signals*/
%}

%x INPUT

var_string [a-z]+

%%

input {
        cout << "BEGIN INPUT" << endl;
        BEGIN INPUT;
      }

[ \n\t\r\f]+

.

<INPUT>{var_string} {
                      cout << "IN INPUT MATCHING var_string:" << yytext << endl;
                      input_num++;
                      input_vec.push_back(yytext);
                    }
<INPUT>; {BEGIN 0;}
<INPUT>,
<INPUT>[ \n\t\r\f]+


%%


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  ifstream input_file("test.v");
  FlexLexer* lexer;
  lexer = new yyFlexLexer(&input_file, &cout);
  while(lexer->yylex()!=0);
  cout << "Input Number: " << input_num << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the Verilog code I want to scan.

```
module test(a, b, c, sum, carry);
input
 a,
 b,
 c;
output
 sum,
 carry;
wire
 d;
assign
 d = (~b & a) | (b & ~a),
 sum = (d & c) | (d & ~c),
 carry= (a & b) | (b & c) | (a & c);
endmodule
```

I except that when the Lex code scan a, b, and c in input section, the output will be:

BEGIN INPUT

IN INPUT MATCHING var_string:a

IN INPUT MATCHING var_string:b

IN INPUT MATCHING var_string:c

Input Number: 3

However, the real output is:

BEGIN INPUT

Input Number: 0

Comment: I can't reproduce this with the snippet you've included, so I assume that you have some other flex rules which are interfering. Please provide a [mcve]. Also, please copy and paste output into your question, rather than linking to an image. It's only a few characters :-)

Comment: @rici, thanks for the suggestion. I've edited my post. Sorry for the bad question style.

Comment: Thanks. I copied the code from your question without modifications, ran it through flex (I have flex 2.6.4) and then compiled it with g++ -Wall. No warnings were produced, and it processed your input file exactly as you expect. I also tried it with v2.5.4, although imho if you are really using that version you need to upgrade; it needs several modifications to work with a non-paleolithic c++ installation. Anyway, it worked fine in that version too.